# How to use OpenTripPlanner on a web application?

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I am new to open trip planner (and OpenStreetMap too), and I would like to use it in a web application, where I would let the user choose preferred options (like travel mode) and even use tags to create a personal route.
Following the tutorial [Basic Usage](http://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Basic-Usage/), I've run the jar file and now I have an instance of OTP running on localhost correctly.
Now, how can I integrate it on a web app and let the user use it? I couldn't find any tutorial about that. Also, I have some other doubts:

- I've downloaded GTFS for Venice, but what do I have to do if I wanted to work with multiple locations?
- Since I have to download also OpenStreetMap data for the same region as the GTFS file (as explained in the tutorial above), again, how it is possible to integrate all the files to, let's say, visualize the roads and create travels on an entire nation?
- How can I use OSM tags to personalize journeys?

I know this is a lot, but I really don't know where to start. Any help, tutorial or guide link would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OTP comes with a default web application that is available after starting the server if you go to localhost:8080.  This is explained in the [Basic Usage](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/) section of the docs.

As for the rest of your question, I'd recommend looking at the [Configuration](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Configuration/) section of the docs.